# Pi 4 doesn't recognise SSD

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, hard-drive, mount, storage

I bought new Pi 4 8GB from authorised seller including power cable. It recognises HDD and works fine. But it doesn't recognise SSD (crucial mx500 1tb sata 2.5-inch 7mm internal ssd). This SSD works fine while connected to my laptop. Can anyone help with this.

Below is the output for disk info when SSD is connected.

```
    rpi~$ df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/root        29G  2.9G   25G  11% /
    devtmpfs        3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           3.9G  8.4M  3.9G   1% /run
    tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   30M  223M  12% /boot
    **/dev/sda1       916G  4.5G  865G   1% /mnt/data**
    tmpfs           782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000
```

For fist few minutes after fresh OS flash, I get the below.

i) `sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0576 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ii) `sudo lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/data
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  29.5G  0 part /sd-root
```

iii) `ls -l /mnt/data`

```
total 28
drwx--x--x 13 root   root    4096 Jun 29 14:56 docker
drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Jun 29 14:56 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Jun 29 14:56 swap
drwxr-xr-x 17 umbrel umbrel  4096 Jul 17 04:00 umbrel
```

After few minutes, SSD becomes unrecognised. Then I get this below.

i) `sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ii) `sudo lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /sd-root
```

iii) `ls -l /mnt/data`

```
ls: reading directory '/mnt/data': Input/output error
total 0
```

iv) `sudo fdisk -l`

<I can't find anything related to Disk /dev/sda>

`dmesg` output shows disk errors

```
...
...
[   10.595923] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   10.724119] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   10.960114] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   11.196175] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   11.217459] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0576, bcdDevice=12.01
[   11.217466] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   11.217472] usb 2-1: Product: External Disk 3.0
[   11.217477] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[   11.217482] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000778899
[   11.219730] usb 2-1: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
[   11.219783] usb 2-1: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
[   11.219789] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   11.220095] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0576: 800000
[   11.220198] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   11.343928] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   11.472120] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   11.708109] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[   11.816111] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[   12.228437] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron  Tech             1201 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   12.228760] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   12.232024] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[   12.232771] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   12.232781] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 00 08
[   12.233409] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   12.260085]  sda: sda1
[   12.262109] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[   12.440588] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[   12.441338] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   12.471953] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   12.996076] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   12.996110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   13.079794] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Setup ERROR: setup address command for slot 1.
[   13.284024] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Setup ERROR: setup address command for slot 1.
[   13.491925] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -22
[   13.619919] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   13.620029] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Setup ERROR: setup address command for slot 1.
[   13.828049] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Setup ERROR: setup address command for slot 1.
[   13.984235] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   13.991948] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[   13.991977] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 0
[   13.997089] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[   13.997198] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=0x00
[   14.039925] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -22
[   14.040150] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[   14.510021] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.eth0.retrans_time_ms instead
[   15.024034] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #60817409: comm rm: reading directory lblock 0
[   15.024146] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #60817409: comm rm: reading directory lblock 0
[   15.034448] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #60817409: comm fallocate: reading directory lblock 0
[   15.175269] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.175385] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   15.175395] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.175418] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.175432] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.175457] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.184493] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   15.184513] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   15.184602] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   15.184830] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   15.402825] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.402836] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.402850] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.963989] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 121667584, lost sync page write
[   20.964014] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[   20.964024] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[   20.964040] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 121667584, lost sync page write
[   20.964051] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[   22.151753] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_journal_check_start:83: Detected aborted journal
[   22.151781] EXT4-fs (sda1): Remounting filesystem read-only
...
...
[   22.156125] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #13369345: comm dockerd: reading directory lblock 0
[   22.156492] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #13369345: comm dockerd: reading directory lblock 0
[   22.156696] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #13369345: comm dockerd: reading directory lblock 0
[   22.156760] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #13369345: comm dockerd: reading directory lblock 0
[   22.156790] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): __ext4_find_entry:1536: inode #13369345: comm dockerd: reading directory lblock 0
[   39.656128] EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:1003: inode #2: lblock 0: comm ls: error -5 reading directory block
```

Comment: For first few minutes after fresh flashing of OS in micro SD, the SSD is recognised and I/O happens. Then it becomes unrecognised. Please find below answers for the questions.

Comment: "Error: External drive disconnected

The external drive was disconnected while Umbrel was running. This can sometimes happen when using an unofficial Raspberry Pi power supply." This error is reported by Umbrel OS (a wrapper around RPi OS) in its web UI. Updated the answer for further inputs.

Comment: Official Raspberry Pi 4 Power Adapter -> https://robocraze.com/products/official-raspberry-pi-4-power-adapter?_pos=1&_psq=Official%20Raspberry%20Pi%204%20Power%20Adapter&_ss=e&_v=1.0

Comment: Orico 2.5" USB 3.0 HDD Enclosure Case Cover for SATA SSD HDD -> (https://www.orico.shop/en/usb-30-hard-drive-enclosure-for-a-25-inch-hard-dri.html) --> For SSD

Comment: Manufacturer -> ORICO Technologies Co., Ltd.

Model No. ORICO 2577U3-BK-EP

Comment: Please don't use comments to improve your question. Instead [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/128133/edit) the question and put it there. I have formatted one code block with 4 space intention for example. You should also do it with the other code blocks.